# How to check if both url are same php

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, preg-match

How to check if two uri are equivalent, But with the following conditions

1. Comparisons of scheme names must be case­insensitive
2. Comparisons of host names must case­insensitive
3. Comparisons of path, hash, and querystring must be case­sensitive
   Paths may contain traversal tokens .(same dir) and ..(one dir up) which must be accounted for
4. Characters are equivalent to their % HEX HEX encodings. (Other than typical reserved
5. characters in urls like , / ? : @ & = + $ #)
6. Query string parameters must be equivalent in arbitrary order, BUT query string arguments of the same name must be listed in the same order in both URIs to be equivalent. There may be multiple (not just 2) args of the same name that need to be accounted for.

In­URI basic auth may be present: e.g.
http://uname:passwd@host.com/foo/bar.html, auth must be case­sensitive

Here is my sample inputs and output

```
uri1: http://example.com:80/~smith/home.html
uri2: http://example.com/%7Esmith/home.html
true
uri1: http://example.com/drill/down/foo.html
uri2: http://example.com/drill/further/../down/./foo.html
true
uri1: http://example.com/foo.html?a=1&b=2
uri2: http://example.com/foo.html?b=2&a=1
true
uri1: http://example.com/foo.html?a=1&b=2&a=3
uri2: http://example.com/foo.html?a=3&a=1&b=2
false
```

Here is What i have tried is

```
<?php
function checkuri($firsturl, $secondurl)
{
$array1=parse_url($firsturl);
$array2=parse_url($secondurl);
if($array1['scheme']==$array2['scheme'])
{
    echo '1. Scheme Matched !<br>';
}
else
{
    echo '1. Scheme not Matched !'; die;
}
if($array1['host']==$array2['host'])
{
    echo '2. Host Matched !<br>';
}
else
{
    echo '2. Host not Matched !'; die;
}
print_r($array1);
print_r($array2);
}
checkuri('http://www.example.com?a=1&b=1','http://www.example.com');
```

Here is the eval [link](https://eval.in/599955)

How can i match the conditions efficiently. Help pls

Comment: You've hardly made any attempt at this. Points 3 to 6 haven't even been touched

Comment: can u help it on it pls. can't get any idea how to assign param values and check it